# Get SocialActions from Linkedin V2 API - permissions error

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, urn

I am using Postman which has been setup via the OAuth 2.0 Authorization and with the following permssions (scope)
`r_liteprofile r_emailaddress rw_organization_admin w_organization_social r_organization_social w_member_social`

I can do a request to the `/me` endpoint fine and it returns relevant data however I am trying to make the following GET request with urn - but getting the error response below what I am doing wrong?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/network-update-social-actions?context=linkedin/compliance/context

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/urn:li:fs_miniCompany:24799518/

// my error in the Postman response

```
{
  "serviceErrorCode": 100,
  "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET /socialActions/urn:li:fs_miniCompany:24799518/",
  "status": 403
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The docs you linked say the URN should be a share, ugc post, or comment URN; it looks like you are passing a company URN (though I would expect a different error if that is the cause).

Also for what it's worth, URNs should be URL-encoded.